# I want to find the ending account balance of an account at the end of the 12 previous months using SQL

Tags: sql-server

I only have the transaction information.

I'm trying to figure out how to write a query that would let me find the ending balance of the previous 2 months (well, 11 eventually) for a dynamically changing account list.

The way that I've thought of but I'm not sure how to execute would be to:

```
SELECT AcctName, CurrTotal - SUM(transactions from the last two months), 
          CurrTotal - SUM(transactions from the last month), CurrTotal;
```

The issue is that I have no idea how to request only the sum of those specific transactions. (Part of that is that I don't know how to find the current date in SQL, so that would help)

For example, I have a Chart of Accounts table, where the info include "AcctName" and "CurrTotal." I have another table for journal entries that includes the amount of the journal entry, the date of the entry, and whether it's a credit or a debit.

```
AcctName    CurrTotal
Checking    45,325
Savings     -65,213
Petty Cash  213,123


EntryID             Amount       Account     Date         Credit/Debit
1                   1,234        Checking    10/15/15     Debit      
2                   15,235       Savings     10/4/15      Credit
3                   32,134       Checking    9/30/15      Debit 
4                   145,111      Savings     9/28/15      Credit
5                   16,234       Savings     9/25/15      Debit
6                   1,000        Petty Cash  9/14/15      Debit
7                   2,532        Checking    9/1/15       Debit
8                   43,213       Savings     8/22/15      Credit
9                   100,323      Checking    8/14/15      Debit
```

Expected Transaction

```
             AUG        SEPT       OCT
Checking    -90,898    9,425      45,325
Savings     122,112    78,899     -65,213
Petty Cash  212,123    213,123    213,123
```

Comment: Please post sample data and expected result.

Comment: Use sqlfiddle.com to create a cenario

Comment: Have you tried using google to search for "sql server get current date"? The top link is exactly what you want.

Comment: @FelixPamittan, I'm working with private company information, and can not post the data. I'll put some mock data in the original question.

Comment: @DerekTomes, I did that, but the four links that I've looked at so far don't tell me how to manipulate the data.

Comment: @phroureo Mock data is enough.

Comment: @phroureo What would be your expected result?

Comment: @FelixPamittan I would expect to see a table that said 

                    AUG          SEPT          OCT
Checking     -90,898     9,425           45,325
Savings       122,112     78,899        -65,213
Petty Cash   212,123     213,123     213,123

Comment: @phroureo Of course. And the rows of that table would be?

Comment: @FelixPamittan, sorry the silly "press enter to finish comment thing" messed me up. I've updated the last comment

Comment: @phroureo, please edit your question and post the expected result.

Comment: @FelixPamittan thanks for your patience. I'm new here.

Comment: @phroureo Your results seems to be incorrect. Can you please explain why `Checking` for `AUG` is `-90,898`.

Comment: Because that was the balance of the account at the beginning of August. (I.E. If you take -90,898 + 100,323 +2,532+32,134+1,234 to check in reverse it comes out to the current balance in the account.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
DECLARE @last_two_months DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0)
DECLARE @last_month DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)

SELECT
    coa.AcctName,
    coa.CurrTotal - SUM(CASE WHEN je.Date >= @last_two_months THEN je.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [AUG],
    coa.CurrTotal - SUM(CASE WHEN je.Date >= @last_month THEN je.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [SEPT],
    coa.CurrTotal AS [OCT]
FROM ChartOfAccounts coa
INNER JOIN JournalEntries je
    ON je.Account = coa.AcctName
GROUP BY
    coa.AcctName, coa.CurrTotal
```

---

[Some common date routines](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/lynnpettis/2009/03/25/some-common-date-routines/)

Comment: Aggregates are new to me. Can you explain what they do and how they work (in brief, of course.)